# script PowerShell não remove variáveis, somente no REPL

Tags: funções, variáveis, powershell

eu tenho dois arquivos PowerShell, no mesmo diretório, com os seguintes scripts:

```
# ARQUIVO "main.ps1"

function play-new {
  param([System.String]$name)
  $global:playQuit = (Get-Location).ToString()
  mksl "$HOME/Tests/$name"
}
function play-quit {
  cd $global:playQuit; Remove-Variable -name "playQuit" -Force
}
```

```
# ARQUIVO "exe-main.ps1"

. main.ps1
play-new "err"
New-Item -Name "main.rb" -ItemType File
play-quit
```

ao executar o `exe-main.ps1` ele alerta

```
        Directory: C:\Users\55549.SAMSUNG-BOOK\Tests


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d----        20/07/2022     12:00                  err

        Directory: C:\Users\55549.SAMSUNG-BOOK\Tests\err


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a---        20/07/2022     12:00              0   main.rb
Remove-Variable: C:\Users\55549.SAMSUNG-BOOK\Tests\err\main.ps1:6
Line |
  28 |  … cd $global:playQuit; Remove-Variable -name "playQuit" -Force}
     |                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot find a variable with the name 'playQuit'.
```

porém quando eu executo logo em seguida `Get-Variable playQuit`, me retorna que existe:

```
> Get-Variable playQuit

Name                           Value
----                           -----
playQuit                       C:\Users\55549.SAMSUNG-BOOK\Tests\err
```

> da mesma forma acontece quando a variável `playQuit` não é `global`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro acontece porque você está tentando remover a variável `playQuit` como se ela tivesse escopo *Local*, que é o valor default do parametro `-Scope` do cmdlet `Remove-Variable`.

Como a variável que você declarou tem o escopo definido como *Global* (`$global:playQuit`), você precisa definir também o escopo *Global* quando for remover a mesma:

```
Remove-Variable -name "playQuit" -Force -Scope Global
```

Referência: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/remove-variable?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: @Bridges369 - se achou a resposta útil, marque a pergunta como respondida. Valeu.